# AlamofireObjectMapper in swift 3

Tags: json, swift3, alamofire, objectmapper

I want to use AlamofireObjectMapper for the first time to parse a json response in swift.

The response is:

```
  "success": true,
  "terms": "https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/terms",
  "privacy": "https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/privacy",
  "timestamp": 1480007048,
  "source": "USD",
  "quotes": {
    "USDAED": 3.672598,
    "USDAFN": 66.599998,
    "USDALL": 127.999937,
    "USDAMD": 478.679993,
    "USDANG": 1.780277,
    "USDAOA": 165.072998,
    "USDARS": 15.497261,
    "USDAUD": 1.348899,
    "USDAWG": 1.79,
    "USDAZN": 1.714104,
    "USDBAM": 1.855297,
    "USDBBD": 2,
    "USDBDT": 79.179735,
    "USDBGN": 1.854199,
    "USDBHD": 0.377036,
    "USDBIF": 1668.300049,
    "USDBMD": 1,
    "USDBND": 1.429902,
    "USDBOB": 6.870014,
    "USDBRL": 3.396898,
    "USDBSD": 1,
}
```

I mapped it like this:

```
class ModelCurrency:  Mappable {

    var success   : Bool?
    var terms     : String?
    var privacy   : String?
    var timestamp : CGFloat?
    var source    : String?
    var quotes    : [Quotes]?

    init() {}

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {

         success<-map["success"]
         terms<-map["terms"]
         privacy<-map["privacy"]
         timestamp<-map["timestamp"]
         source<-map["source"]
         quotes<-map["quotes"]

        print("It json\(terms)")
    }
}

class Quotes : Mappable {

    var name : String?
    var val : CGFloat?

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        name<-map["name"]
        val<-map["val"]
    }
}
```

And in my controller:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        super.viewDidLoad()
        let URL = "http://www.apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=ad847a0a855c0647590df2b818923025"

 Alamofire.request(URL).responseArray(queue: "quotes") { (response: DataResponse<[Quotes]>) in
            let arrayCurency = response.result.value!


                for quotes in arrayCurency {
                    print(quotes.name!)
                    print(quotes.val!)
                }

        }

    }
```

It gives me error mapping and this error:

> cannot convert value 'String' to expected argument type 'DispatchQueue?'

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues.

1. You want to reference `DataResponse<ModelCurrency>` rather than `DataResponse<[Quotes]>`.
2. You want to use `responseObject`, not `responseArray`.
3. You don't want to use that `queue` parameter with a `String` value. The `queue` parameter is used to specify which dispatch queue you want the completion handlers to run. But that's not what you're doing here, so you should just remove it.
4. The value associated with the `quotes` key is not an array of objects. It is yet another dictionary. So you should map it to a dictionary, and then use `map` method to convert that to an array of `Quote` objects.

So, pulling that all together:

```
Alamofire.request(urlString).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<ModelCurrency>) in
    ...
}
```

And

```
class ModelCurrency:  Mappable {

    var success   : Bool?
    var terms     : String?
    var privacy   : String?
    var timestamp : CGFloat?
    var source    : String?
    var quotes    : [Quote]?

    required init?(map: Map) { }

    func mapping(map: Map) {

        success    <- map["success"]
        terms      <- map["terms"]
        privacy    <- map["privacy"]
        timestamp  <- map["timestamp"]
        source     <- map["source"]

        var dictionary: [String: CGFloat]?
        dictionary <- map["quotes"]
        quotes = dictionary?.map { return Quote(name: $0.key, val: $0.value) }
    }
}

class Quote {

    var name : String?
    var val : CGFloat?

    init(name: String?, val: CGFloat?) {
        self.name = name
        self.val  = val
    }

}
```

(I've renamed `Quotes` to `Quote` as it would appear to be a quote for a single currency.)

Comment: I did as you said but I have an error in a row for quotes in arrayCurency error: Type ModelCurrency does not conform to protocol Sequence.What shall I do ?

Comment: the first i rwite responsObject  i  have got  error :
Type 'ModelCurrence' does not conform to protocol Sequence swift
But i write responce Array  i have got  error : Value tupe  ModelCurrence has not member a 'name' and  'val'

Comment: Alamofire.request(URL).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<ModelCurrency>) in
    
        let arrayCurency = response.result.value!

                for quotes in arrayCurency {
                    print(quotes.name!)
                    print(quotes.val!)
                }
        
        }

Comment: `Alamofire.request(URL).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<ModelCurrency>) in let currency = response.result.value!; for quotes in currency.quotes { print(quotes.name!); print(quotes.val!) } }`

Comment: Very well thank you for the help)
I first write to Swift
Everything works

Comment: I have another question
How can I add JSON in array? and displaying array in tableView?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but rather than us trying to tease that out here in comments, I'd suggest you post a separate question.

Comment: I want array quotes displayed in tableview. How to do it ?

Comment: I think if you go through any modern table view tutorial, it will become self-evident. Google "Swift 3 UITableView tutorial". It's certainly too broad of a question for me to answer here. It probably isn't even a valid question for Stack Overflow. The only trick is that you have to call `tableView.reloadData()` when you're done asynchronously retrieving your quotes.

Comment: How to mapping only on certain condition. I have a login API which gives details only if user detalils are correct. other wise i will get status as "failure"   . So how do mapping only on succeses ?

Comment: Have the `init` method return `nil` if a certain condition was met, a la https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/b91cb172dd4cff2bfc3b37766eff2d1b

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this part of code:

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
    name<-map["name"]
    val<-map["val"]
}
```

in Quotes.

What you should do is map dictionary:

```
var quotes: [String : CGFloat] = [:]
```

and when mapping use:

```
quotes  <- map["quotes"]
```

Take a look at:

https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper

at the basics there is mapping dictionary.

To be more specific, in quote object you don't have name and val JSON objects, it is just what you want. If you map it to dictionary you will be able to access theses values.

Haven't seen your image - but if you don't change above the app will crash.

For the above issue you need to provide queue in which you want to run your request, if you don't want to mess with that and you actually want keyPath, then you need to call function with `keyPath:` instead of `queue:`. Link:

https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper

look for Array Responses

Comment: My probleme is .responseArray(queue: "quotes") error cannot convert value 'String' to expected argument type 'DispatchQueue?' I write var quotes: [String : CGFloat] = [:] it changed nothing.    var success   : Bool?
    var terms     : String?
    var privacy   : String?
    var timestamp : CGFloat?
    var source    : String?
  
    var quotes: [String : CGFloat] = [:]

Comment: Take a look at the rest of the answer - have you tried instead of queue to provide keyPath ?